# How do you animate Unity Time.timeScale using an easing function with DOTween?

Tags: unity-game-engine, dotween

I'm trying to animate `Time.timescale` using an easing function with DOTween.

Tweening the value itself seems to work:

`DG.Tweening.DOTween.To(value => Time.timeScale = value, 1, 0, 0.4f);`

But all the SetX() methods mentioned in the documentation are not available on the object this returns and while I found out that I could set the `timeScale` property, there doesn't seem to be any way to use an easing function for this tween.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out:

Unfortunately it seems that all SetX() methods in DOTween are implemented as extension methods. This means that these methods are simply not available if you are trying to use DOTween by specifying the full type, rather than including the namespace.

This works:

```
using DG.Tweening;
///
DOTween.To(()=> Time.timeScale, x=> Time.timeScale = x, 2, 0.4f).SetEase(Ease.InQuad).SetUpdate(true);
```

This does **not work**:

```
DG.Tweening.DOTween.To(()=> Time.timeScale, x=> Time.timeScale = x, 2, 0.4f).SetEase(DG.Tweening.Ease.InQuad).SetUpdate(true);
```

Comment: It seems to work without the DOTween on your SetEase chain method, i,e. :

DG.Tweening.DOTween.To(()=> Time.timeScale, x=> Time.timeScale = x, 2, 0.4f).SetEase(DG.Tweening.Ease.InQuad).SetUpdate(true);

Comment: sorry, was a minor mistake in my example (corrected). the fact remains that you have to use 'using DG.Tweening' for the SetEase() and SetUpdate() methods to be valid calls. That's because they are implemented as extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're wanting to pause execution by slowing time down gradually rather than instantaneously stopping it and you want to use an easing method.

To set an ease on a DOTween just add on the Ease method call via chaining like this:

```
DG.Tweening.DOTween.To(value => Time.timeScale = value, 1, 0, 0.4f).SetEase(Ease.InCubic));
```

Chain more methods together like this, this runs Debug.Log on every Update call:

```
DG.Tweening.DOTween.To(value => Time.timeScale = value, 1, 0, 0.4f).OnUpdate(()=>{ Debug.Log(Time.timeScale); }).SetEase(Ease.InCubic);
```

Running this code shows that Time.timeScale doesn't actually get to zero, probably due to floating point precision errors; however, using the OnUpdate chain method Time.timeScale can be assigned zero once it gets close enough:

```
DG.Tweening.DOTween.To(value => Time.timeScale = value, 1, 0, 0.4f).OnUpdate(()=>{ if (Time.timeScale < 0.001f) Time.timeScale = 0; }).SetEase(Ease.InCubic);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I think I'm missing something because I don't have a .SetEase(), nor a OnUpdate() method available.

Comment: That's strange.  Check out this link and search the page for "Chained callbacks" (without the quotes): http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php
You should have all of those methods at your disposal, OnUpdate, OnComplete, OnStart, etc.

Comment: Thanks, for your help. I figured it out. See my own answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32727494/10779 - silly mistake to make.